# Is arcgis-workflow-manager more suitable tag for ArcGIS Workflow Manager than wmx?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

An [Answer to an earlier Meta Question suggested/requested](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3077/how-to-suggest-tag-synonyms/3181#3181) that the tag for the [ArcGIS Workflow Manager](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/arcgis-workflow-manager) (formerly known as the Job Tracking extension) follow [Stack Exchange GIS tag naming conventions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/tagging):

> **How to format tags**
>
> - Use all lower case
> - Replace spaces with hyphens (-) to combine multiple words into a single word (e.g., tag "unit testing" as unit-testing)
> - Avoid punctuation (which can make it difficult to use the tag in a URL)
> - When naming a tag, think about how someone would search for that subject. In most cases this means typing out the full name, but you
>     may also want to use the abbreviation. For example, [css] is probably
>     more appropriate than [cascading-style-sheets]

However, there is currently a tag of [wmx](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wmx) with synonyms [arcgis-workflow-manager](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-workflow-manager) and [jtx](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jtx) which is the reverse of the suggestion/request.

What should be the master tag for the [ArcGIS Workflow Manager](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/arcgis-workflow-manager)?

Comment: Try this: begin asking a question and start typing these tag names into the "Tags" form. Before anything relevant appears in the first case you have to type "arcgis-w" but in the second case "wm" will do it.  You will be successful in either situation.  Also, if you include "site:gis.stackexchange.com" in the Google search all 12 questions with either tag show up.  So is there any reason to be concerned about which is the master and which is the synonym?

Comment: @whuber If I were asking a Desktop Question I would type "de" (I actually type "desk") and find [tag:arcgis-desktop] but if I am asking a Workflow Manager Question I would type "wo" (probably "work") and not be offered [tag:wmx] (or [tag:arcgis-workflow-manager] which is what I would have expected).  I have never included "site:gis.stackexchange.com" in a Google search.

Comment: I use Google's `site:` operator all the time, very useful. I agree though that `wmx` is not the best or most searchable tag for this product and `arcgis-workflow-manager` should be the master. Most people I know that use it refer to it as either "workflow manager" or "JTX" (from when it used to be called the Job Tracking eXtension), but rarely do I hear it referred to as "WMX". And if you type "workflow" into the tags search window, all you get is the `workflow` tag.

Comment: PolyGeo and @Blah: The reason you don't get [tag:wmx] until you have typed "workfl" is that there are many tags containing "work" *that are much more popular than this one,* so they are preferentially shown. As far as I know, for tag searches (which includes the automatic search conducted when adding tags to a post) *it does not matter which term is the master* because the search system looks through them all. Thus reversing the master-synonym relationship would not change this behavior.

Comment: @whuber, it looks like there is different behavior on the tags page search box and the question tags box. The former appears to only suggest tags whose name at least partially match the query term, but the latter works as you describe.

Comment: @Poly Thank you for the clarification. I was not aware this was your aim, because I interpret the SE naming conventions differently. Specifically, my reading has focused on the admonition to "think about how someone would search for that subject. In most cases this means typing out the full name, but you may also want to use the abbreviation. For example, `[css]` is probably more appropriate than `[cascading-style-sheets]`..."  I thereby would not view all abbreviations as "litter" and would accept them in any cases that they might help users perform searches.

Comment: I identified the case for well known abbreviations like CSS (see Question) but WMX is much less used than its fuller names (see Question).

Comment: So what is the objection to this? It's been over a year since the original request. Is it just that no one else uses the software? :)

Comment: @blah238 I find it hard to fathom - pro [tag:arcgis-workflow-manager] as master seems to be that it follows guidelines, reinforcing pride in our site, and is more likely to be successful in searches - con seems to be that WMX was made master (albeit against advice) and also appears on the internet so some results are returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I work through the guidelines cited in the question, I conclude that making [arcgis-workflow-manager](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-workflow-manager) the master follows them more closely:

1. The product name is **[ArcGIS Workflow Manager](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/arcgis-workflow-manager)** - to see this click the link to visit its product page.
2. Turn "ArcGIS Workflow Manager" to lowercase and we get "arcgis workflow manager"
3. Replacing spaces with hyphens gives us "arcgis-workflow-manager"
4. There is no punctuation to confuse the picture
5. To override the above and use an abbreviation instead is OK in an ***exceptional*** case like CSS where a Google search of ["css"](https://www.google.com/?q=css#q=css) returns 128 million hits and["cascading style sheet"](https://www.google.com/?q=cascading%20style%20sheet#q=cascading%20style%20sheet) only returns one million
6. If ["wmx"](https://www.google.com/search?q=wmx#q=wmx) is used to search Google then you will have to look through a LOT of pages to find a hit
7. In contrast if ["arcgis workflow manager"](https://www.google.com/search?q=wmx#q=arcgis%20workflow%20manager) is used to search Google then the first page is full of hits and even when the more generic ["workflow manager"](https://www.google.com/search?q=wmx#q=workflow%20manager) is looked for it is on the first page and only knocked down to the fourth item returned by the Workflow Manager of Microsoft.
8. If we type ["wmx"](http://resources.arcgis.com/search/index.cfm?do=search&q=wmx&num=25&lg=en&product=&subject=&version=&collection=help&filter=p) into an **[ArcGIS Resources](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/home/)** search of the **Help** (sidebar option) then you do get 37 hits, but type in ["arcgis workflow manager"](http://resources.arcgis.com/search/index.cfm?do=search&start=0&lg=en&collection=help&filter=p&q=%22arcgis%20workflow%20manager%22&searchLanguage=0) to get 197, or ["workflow manager"](http://resources.arcgis.com/search/index.cfm?do=search&start=0&lg=en&collection=help&filter=p&q=%22workflow%20manager%22&searchLanguage=0) to get 421.

I see this product commonly referred to by a (more) complete name (Workflow Manager or ArcGIS Workflow Manager), and only occasionally by an abbreviation (WMX), so I think people will far more often search for it using strings like "workflow manager" than "wmx".