# Should answers on "How to suggest tag synonyms?" be deleted once implemented?

Tags: discussion, status-deferred, tags

@ChrisW and I have had some discussion this evening/morning in comments to my [answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3758/115) on  [Make suggesting synonyms privilege that kicks in at reputation of around 1,000?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3077/how-to-suggest-tag-synonyms)

@AndreSilva had suggested that deletion of answers on that *particular* question was a useful way of cleaning up tag synonym suggestions that had already been implemented' and it struck me as being a very good idea, to bring the question back to its original intention, which was to try and get the threshold at which users could suggest synonyms lowered.

My question here is whether all answers to the question [Make suggesting synonyms privilege that kicks in at reputation of around 1,000?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3077/how-to-suggest-tag-synonyms) that pertain to actually suggesting a synonym, rather than to how to make it easier to suggest tag synonyms, should be deleted (once they are implemented)?

If the "Yes vote" is strong then there will be some (just a few) not yet implemented answers, that are still under discussion, and I think these should be pulled out into their own Q&As but let's treat that as another question once this one has been discussed.

Comment: Someone should probably post a 'yes delete them' answer - my upvote on the question is because I think it a topic worth examination, not that I would want to see them deleted.

Comment: I second Chris's idea of posting suggestions as new questions. Like I said I was reluctant about the idea of deleting answers (because they added value), but in that/this particular case the thread was/is so cluttered that maybe its original purpose started to lose effect (cc/ @ChrisW).

Comment: I think the idea to post tag suggestions as new questions is a [shared one](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3758/115).

Comment: @ChrisW done -- added an alternative, 'yes delete them' answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as someone who *can* see the deleted answers in the tag synonym suggestion question, I can tell you it is pretty messy, and can fully understand the desire to delete them as a way of cleaning it up (and also acknowledging progress), and not much would be lost by deleting them (since they aren't really gone, just hidden to lower-rep users).

In fact, I just deleted as many of my own answers to that question as I could, which apparently is 5 per day.

So I guess if you are in favor of deleting those crusty old tag suggestion answers, vote this up!

I fully agree with moving forward with this part of Chris's answer, however:

> I'd go ahead and accept your latest answer, then close the question so no new answers can be added. At that point, all new suggestions can be new questions, and your accepted answer will direct people both to post them as such and visit the relevant SE Meta questions to vote on changing how the system itself works.

Comment: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3077/how-to-suggest-tag-synonyms is now on hold, and expected to become closed soon.

Comment: Again, the ones with no discussion or anything to them hold no value and are fine to delete so I don't completely disagree with your answer. But the more extensive ones I think do, and if deleted that information will be hidden to all but (currently) 27 non-"lower-rep" people out of however many users we have (by one metric, 1400+ that have voted more than 10 times). With the idea of moving to new questions for new suggestions, cleanup largely becomes moot imho.

Answer (score 3):

To reiterate my position from those other comments:

I disagree with deleting those synonym suggestion answers, and would disagree *strongly* if not for the fact they are still around and visible by at least some people. They provide documentation, and are helpful for people considering making other suggestions (demonstrating the format of pointing out number of questions, Wiki descriptions, and other factors) as well as details of tags under discussion. Tags have history but that shows only edits; not any discussion or rationale of why beyond a brief edit statement. Some suggestions have no real discussion or even detailed proposal logic, so not much would be lost. Others have a lot more to them.

I'm not a fan of the restrictions on the ability to view deleted posts (though I understand the moderation logic of not having everyone be able to see them), since in cases like this the people who would most need to see it can't (ie bringing a suggestion or its reversal up again). In fact, without that high rep level (10k) or being the original asker, nobody can see it - including if you commented or answered it, which really irks me sometimes. But that's a whole other topic. Suffice to say I think the discussion/rationale aspect of synonym suggestions is beneficial for all, and oppose deletion for anything with such value (again, not all of them have that). If each suggestion is its own question this becomes moot unless you also propose deleting those questions as they are addressed.

I understand the desire to get that question back on track in terms of who can suggest rather than suggestions. But is that something we at GIS.SE can control independently of the main SE system? If scoring is tied and we can't alter it, the question would belong only on SE Meta and cleanup wouldn't really serve much of a purpose. Otherwise I wouldn't be overly opposed to pulling out unaddressed suggestions to new questions, though I don't know how beneficial being retroactive in this case would be. Seems easier to just shut it down and make the change moving forward.

**To summarize:** I wouldn't delete any answers there to clean it up. I'd go ahead and accept your latest answer, then close the question so no new answers can be added. At that point, all new suggestions can be new questions, and your accepted answer will direct people both to post them as such and visit the relevant SE Meta questions to vote on changing how the system itself works.