# Should [qgs] and [qgis-project] tags be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Should we make these two tags synonyms?

It seems that currently open questions in [qgs](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgs) seem to be a bit more about the file format / XML content (and its creation or manipulation outside of QGIS) and questions in [qgis-project](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-project) more about using projects from within QGIS, but there is significant thematic overlap and the current tag names don't really reflect that distinction.

Comment: Sounds likely to me, which are you proposing would be the master and which the synonym?

Comment: I'm not sure. If we want the new meaning to be specifically about the project files and their (raw, XML) content, their creation, manipulation etc., then a new tag name, e.g. [tag:qgis-project-file] might make that more apparent. I that case, the to-be-synonym tags should be removed from questions that are (only) about the QGIS concept of a "project", disregarding the storage specifics. These questions might not need a specific new tag, the plain [tag:qgis] tag might suffice there, I think.

Comment: @das-g Please [edit] and expand your question to include these extra thoughts from your comment

Comment: Edited [comment](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4623/should-qgs-and-qgis-project-tags-be-synonyms#comment8453_4623) content into question. (Or should that have been an "answer" in this not-really-a-question-but-a-discussion?)

Comment: For structuring Q&As about tag and tag synonym proposals you may like to review https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3820/guidelines-for-proposing-tag-synonyms  At the moment it seems like you have complicated what seemed initially like a straightforward proposal for synonymizing two tags by adding another tag into the discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Following https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3822/51574 I've extracted my proposed solution (incl. its complication) to an answer.

Comment: Should I post the two obvious alternative, less complicated solutions (make [tag:qgs] a synonym of [tag:gis-project] or vice versa, not introducing any new tags in either case) as separate answers, or should that be done by whoever would prefer those solutions?

Comment: Rather than have this Q&A drag on, it looks the voting is 12-0 on a change being desirable (7 on the question plus 3 and 2 on the two answers.  Which of the two answers to implement is far from clear cut but I am going to implement the one which is currently leading because it is simpler by virtue of requiring no new tag.  If the voting does swing around then changing the implemented scheme to the other one proposed is very easy to do.

Comment: sounds good :-)

Answer (score 3):

I rarely use QGIS so this is an "outsider" opinion but I would favour simply making:

- [qgis-project](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-project) a synonym of [qgs](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgs) (and not coining another tag for [qgis-project-file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-project-file))

By way of analogy I think we should also make the ArcGIS "equivalent" of [mapdocument](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mapdocument) a synonym of [mxd](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mxd).

Answer (score 2):

To have the new meaning be specifically about the project *files* and their (raw, XML) content, their creation, manipulation etc.

- introduce the new tag name [qgis-project-file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-project-file) that makes this intended meaning more obvious
- make [qgs](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgs) and [qgis-project](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-project) synonyms of that tag
- remove [qgis-project](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-project) (and [qgs](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgs)) from questions that are about the general QGIS concept of projects but not about those projects on-disk representation or its manipulation. [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis) should suffice for those questions, as you can't really work with QGIS without a QGIS project anyway.