# Updating FME tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

As you may know, FME underwent a rebranding exercise recently. I've made a few suggested edits for tags, but I don't think I have the reputation to sort out synonyms properly. I'm also not sure which way around synonyms ought to point.

For the rebranding:

- FME Desktop became FME Form
- FME Server became FME Flow
- FME Cloud became FME Flow Hosted

Right now, the FME tags on the site are:

- fme
- fme-transformer
- fme-server
- fmeobjects
- fme-cloud
- fme-form
- fme-flow
- fme-desktop
- fme-workbench

I just created the `fme-form` and `fme-flow` tags.

So, would `fme-desktop` become a synonym for `fme-form`, or should it be the other way around? And the same question for `fme-server` becoming a synonym for `fme-flow`, and `fme-cloud` for `fme-flow-hosted`.

To be honest, some of those tags aren't particularly useful - for example, `fme-workbench` - and we could maybe delete that one?

I know there are already some synonyms, and I'm not sure if they are helpful or not.

Answer (score 1):

You have followed our [Guidelines for proposing tag synonyms](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3820/guidelines-for-proposing-tag-synonyms), which lead me to think that we should use moderator tools to implement this quickly.

I propose that we do the following as soon as community consensus is clear:

1. Merge [fme-desktop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fme-desktop) as a synonym of [fme-form](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fme-form)
2. Merge [fme-server](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fme-server) as a synonym of [fme-flow](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fme-flow)
3. Merge [fme-cloud](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fme-cloud) as a synonym of [fme-flow-hosted](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fme-flow-hosted)

Once that has been done, and/or if additional proposals are made, we can proceed to deal with any other existing FME tags that need attention.